# How can I extract a variable dependent on context to the class from a method to avoid duplicating code?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation, refactoring

I have two classes.

The main class is a GraphQL query resolver:

```
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
class UserProfileQuery implements GraphQLQueryResolver {

    private final UserProfileRepository userProfileRepository;
    private final AddressRepository addressRepository;
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final UserProfileAccessValidator validator;

    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ACCOUNT_OWNER')")
    public Optional<List<UserProfile>> getUserProfiles(Long accountId) {
        User user = userRepository.findById(LoggedUserHolder.getUserId()).orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException(User.class));
        validator.validateAccountOwnerAccess(user, accountId);
        return userProfileRepository.findMatchingAccountId(accountId);
    }

    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ACCOUNT_OWNER')")
    public Optional<UserProfile> getUserProfile(Long userProfileId) {
        User user = userRepository.findById(LoggedUserHolder.getUserId()).orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException(User.class));
        User checkedUser = userRepository.findByUserProfileId(userProfileId).orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException(User.class));
        validator.validateAccountOwnerAccess(user, checkedUser);
        return userProfileRepository.findById(userProfileId);
    }

    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('ACCOUNT_OWNER','USER')")
    public Set<Address> getAddresses(Long userProfileId) {
        User user = userRepository.findById(LoggedUserHolder.getUserId()).orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException(User.class));
        User checkedUser = userRepository.findByUserProfileId(userProfileId).orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException(User.class));
        validator.validateAccountOwnerAndUserAccess(user, checkedUser);
        return Optional.of(addressRepository.findByUserProfileId(userProfileId)).orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException(UserProfile.class));
    }

}
```

The second class is a validator:

```
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserProfileAccessValidator {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public void validateAccessForUserCreation(CreateUserProfileCommand command) {
        User user = userRepository.findById(LoggedUserHolder.getUserId()).orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException(User.class));
        User checkedUser = userRepository.findById(command.getUserId()).orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException(User.class));
        validateAccountOwnerAndUserAccess(user, checkedUser);
    }

    public void validateAccountOwnerAndUserAccess(User user, User checkedUser) {
        if (AccessValidationHelper.isAccountOwnerAndHasSameAccount(user, checkedUser)
                || AccessValidationHelper.isUserAndHasSameUserProfileId(user, checkedUser)) {
            throw new IllegalOperationException();
        }
    }

    public void validateAccountOwnerAccess(User user, User checkedUser) {
        if (AccessValidationHelper.isAccountOwnerAndHasSameAccount(user, checkedUser)) {
            throw new IllegalOperationException();
        }
    }

    public void validateAccountOwnerAccess(User user, Long accountId) {
        if (!user.getAccount().getId().equals(accountId)) {
            throw new IllegalOperationException();
        }
    }

}
```

As You can see, there is a lot of code duplication of User fetching.

```
    User user = userRepository.findById(LoggedUserHolder.getUserId()).orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException(User.class));
    User checkedUser = userRepository.findById(command.getUserId()).orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException(User.class));
```

How could I refactor both classes to avoid this code duplication? Or at least to avoid duplication of:

```
    User user = userRepository.findById(LoggedUserHolder.getUserId()).orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException(User.class));
```

Cause it is taking the user from Spring context holder. I am sitting on this problem since an hour and I have no good solution to implement...

Answer (score 0):

If the logged user is the Principal you could use a @PreAuthorize expression. If that works for you, then you can use meta-annotation. With meta-annotation you can reduce the amount of code. Here is a nice tutorial on how to use them: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-method-security

Comment: Yep, but I still have to dive into the database to fetch data needed for the validator checks, because just being an ACCOUNT_OWNER or USER is not enough for the checks to work :(

Comment: An option is to add the information you lookup from DB into the Principal, then DB lookup is not nescessary. This can be done by implementing your own UserDetails and UserDetailsService.

Answer (score 0):

You should move both the common code to a Utility class(lets say UserUtility), declare that class as @Component, create method that performs desired operation on the User and then autowire that in your two classes and use it to get the common result.

Hope this helps.